# Access to fields of native application from node.js

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js

I have a native Android (Java) mobile application but now I have to run node.js server on client side. I'm new to all this stuff, so I decided to use Node.js for Mobile Apps (https://code.janeasystems.com/nodejs-mobile) to run my index.js file.
I have added all needed NDK staff according to instructions and everything works fine till this moment in JS code:

```
  const o = {
                serverUrl: process.env.SERVER_URL,
                token: process.env.TOKEN,
             ...
            };
```

JS code for some reasons unable to see ".env" file

```
NODEJS-MOBILE: path.js:28
throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
```

and even if be able - java part will not be able to update TOKEN field because it's impossible to write to file with empty name (at least, I didn't succeed).

So, the question is what instruments (local files/libraries/SharedPreferences?) I can use to be able to update fields from java code and use them in JS code?

I'm new to non-native development, so any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: "Node.js for Mobile Apps" -- interesting!

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be easier than I thought.

> The process.argv property returns an array containing the command-line
> arguments passed when the Node.js process was launched.

[Node.js for Mobile Apps library](https://code.janeasystems.com/nodejs-mobile) allows to use it like this:

```
  startNodeWithArguments(new String[]{"node",
                nodeDir + "/index.js",
                Constants.SERVER_URL,
                Constants.USER_TOKEN,
                ...
        });
```

And then, in js file we can get this values like this:

```
 const o = {
                    serverUrl: process.argv[2],
                    token: process.argv[3],
                    ...
            };
```

**UPD:**

I have found one more solution to use environment variables without .env file.
In "startNodeWithArguments()" it's possbile to use "setenv()" method.

```
startNodeWithArguments(JNIEnv *env, jobject, jobjectArray arguments) {

    const char *token = env->GetStringUTFChars((jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement(arguments, 2), nullptr);

    setenv("TOKEN", token, 1);
...
}
```